# Mlflow artifacts stored in EC2 behind AWS ECS instead of S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, mlflow

I am using AWS ECS for creating a Mlflow server and the artifacts which where supposed to stored in S3 bucket are stored in the ec2 instance running behind the ECS service.I am executing the test.py file below from my local codebase.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.0

RUN pip3 install mlflow pymysql boto3

CMD mlflow server \
  --backend-store-uri my.rds.url \
  --artifacts-destination s3://bucket-url/mlflow \
  --host 0.0.0.0 \
  --serve-artifacts
```

My ECS container having mlflow server is instead saving the artifacts on the ec2 instance running behind the ECS cluster as the cluster is enabled to support both fargate and ec2 type.

My experimental file test.py:

```
import mlflow 
import pymysql
import boto3
tracking_uri = 'my.custom.url'
experiment_name = 'new-exp1'
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)
mlflow.create_experiment(experiment_name)
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)
print(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()) # This should be 'http://localhost:5000' 
print(mlflow.get_artifact_uri()) # This should be '${mlruns_artifacts}/0/${uuid}/artifacts' 
mlflow.log_param("test_param", 0)
mlflow.log_metric('test_metric', 1) 
mlflow.log_artifact("/testfile.txt")   #Same directory as in test.py
```